# dynamic css grid | height doesn't apply to second row

Tags: html, css

I want to create a dynamic grid.

this is my current css. What am i missing that the row hight is not applied to the second row?

```
.container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 170px);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, 300px);
}
```

[image]

html:

```
<div class="container">
   <div>
       css
   </div>
   <div>
      html
   </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please provide HTML markup as well as CSS so people can see what you have so far

Comment: @NickScotney added the ground structure. Is that enough? In my opinion more code just makes it complicated. When i use !important i get the same result.

Comment: use `grid-auto-rows: 300px` instead